# Understanding The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Part 1

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

First Part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that "**the derivative of a definite integral with respect to its upper limit is the integrand evaluated at the upper limit.**"
So it means that the antiderivative of integrand evaluated at the upper limit is it's integral? Can you please explain for me how it works?

So it says that for
$$g(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = f(x)$$

So does it mean that we can find an integral from a to x, by finding antiderivative of f(x)? If so where does a go?

Comment: Bad idea to state a theorem in Math avoiding basic symbols. It is saying that $\frac  d{dx} \int_a^{x} f(t)dt=f(x)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm got it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked whether it means:

> ...we can find an integral from $a$ to $x$ by finding antiderivative of $f(x)$?

No, this is not what it means. What is means is exactly the opposite:

> ... we can find an antideritive of $f(x)$ by finding an integral from $a$ to $x$.

You can tell that's what the theorem says if you pay attention not only to the *conclusion* of the theorem, but also its *hypothesis*. To add to the excellent comment of @geetha290krm, it's a bad idea to state a theorem in math avoiding its hypothesis.

The hypothesis of this theorem is:

> Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Right away you can see: you already have the function $f$ in your hand. Your goal is to find an antiderivative of it. And the way you find that antiderivative is given in the conclusion of the theorem:

> For $g(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$, we have $\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only thing which is unclear for me - Why do we use some F(x) = g(x) + C, instead of using g(x) itself in the second part of this theorem?

Comment: That's another issue, but I'll say that the goal of Part I is to get just one antiderivative $g(x)$. Once you have that one, you can then use another argument to conclude that every other antiderivative can be written in the form $g(x)+C$ for different values of the constant $C$.